# Set various limits on child process programmatically (Linux)

Tags: c++, c, linux, resources, operating-system

I know how to use setrlimit() and getrlimit() system calls. I'm trying to impose some limits on a child process. First, I'm forking a child, then I'm setting various limits in child, after what I'm replacing process image with real child using exec call (limits survive exec call). I have a few questions:

1.Limiting memory usage - currently it is not all that clear to me which flag should I use for that. RLIMIT_DATA is one controlling sbrk() and brk() calls, but I've found that glibc malloc implementation uses mmap() which is controlled with RLIMIT_AS flag. So if I want to limit memory usage to 16MB should I call:

```
    struct rlimit mlimit;
    mlimit.rlim_cur = 1 << 23;
    mlimit.rlim_max = mlimit.rlim_cur;
    ::setrlimit(RLIMIT_DATA, &mlimit);
    ::setrlimit(RLIMIT_AS, &mlimit);
```

or I should use only one option?

2.Limiting number of open file descriptors - if I want to prevent child process from opening any additional file descriptors, other then the ones for *stdin*, *stdout* and *stderr* should I then set RLIMIT_NOFILE to 4 (a value one greater than the maximum file descriptor number as specified in man pages)?

3.Limiting total amount of file writes - there is a RLIMIT_FSIZE flag and it is stated in the man pages that this flag has next semantics:

> The maximum size of files that the process may create. Attempts to extend a file beyond this limit result in delivery of a SIGXFSZ signal.

If I understood it correctly this flag imposes limit on a max size of a single file - not cumulative size of all files written by process. Hence the question is should I use this flag in combination with RLIMIT_NOFILE to limit how much data can be written to disk in total, or there is a better way to do it?

4.Preventing child from changing this limits - untrusted code will be executed with exec call so I'm wondering if there is a way for this child process to override limits that were set after fork() but before exec call? If it can be done how can I prevent it? I've read a little about capabilities and CAP_SYS_RESOURCE but it is not clear to me how to do it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These limits will not be exact and using them will cause lots of problems. Notably:

- when you use `RLIMIT_AS` you are limiting the shared libraries that can be loaded to the process - if you update Glibc, it can be that the new Glibc will push the size over limits and your program will not run anymore
- For file descriptors - the process can always close the standard stream descriptors to open more, but if you give too little, the dynamic linker will be unable to link in the C library for you.
- The `RLIMIT_FSIZE` will be *per file*, as you have found out.

The `setrlimit` documentation says that an unprivileged process can only lower the hard limit, not increase it, so when you set the hard limit, that process or its children cannot increase it, unless they have the `CAP_SYS_RESOURCE`, which no non-root process ought to have by default.

Comment: First let me thank you for your answer. I need to use this limits so let me ask you a few more questions. I've seen that sbrk() is used only to move border of data segment so I need to limit mmap(). So right thing to do would be to set RLIMIT_AS to: memory needed for libc + my imposed limit. Any ideas how can I achieve this?